# - initWithCoder: when -decodeObjectOfClass:forKey: returns nil

Tags: objective-c, encode

I'm wondering how to use `NSSecureCoding` when a given property was `nil` when encoded. Take the following example:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        _buffer = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSMutableData class] forKey:@"buffer"];

        if (_buffer == nil) {
            self = nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder setValue:_buffer forKey:@"buffer"];
}
```

I created the habit of setting `self` to `nil` whenever an allocation fails, as it seems like a correct pattern. However, in this case, if `_buffer` was `nil` when encoded, how can I tell that from allocation failure when decoding?

Comment: I don't think you should set self to nil. you create the object and one of its properties is nil. what's wrong about that?

Comment: It's wrong because it has not been properly initialised. For instance, lets say that I was initialising with data (`-initWithData:`). At some point, I would copy the data (`_buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data]`). If after that `_buffer` is `nil` (allocation failed) the object has not been properly initialised. You shouldn't return `self` as if nothing happened, because something did happen. By return `self` (non `nil`) you would be telling the caller that everything wen't OK, and that's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the pattern you're trying to handle here, but using `setValue:` directly on the coder I suspect is odd. I've only ever used, and seen, the `encode<SomeThing>: forKey:` syntax used. And from what I'm looking at, then trying to decode for that same key is going to result in a bad output.

But you're saying you want to distinguish between a resulting decode that is actually null, and a failure state where you've chosen to return a null value? I'm still not sure why you are handling it that way, but the only way to distinguish would be to choose a different value to store like "The Buffer has a nil value" and then checking for that string on decode, or storing a second key on the coder that you would check against:

```
if(_buffer == nil){
  [aCoder encodeBool: true forKey: @"wasBufferNull"];
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! I didn't even notice I was using `-setValue:forKey:`. I usually use `-encodeObject:forKey:`, of course. It's a nice idea to encode a second key. It's just a bit unfortunate that `NSCoder` does not handle that, though. I'll give it a few more time before accepting, just in case there's a better alternative out there and somebody responds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you asked this question. But in case anyone else is still interested to find a solution…

For `NSData` / `NSMutableData`, one idea on how to differentiate whether `nil` as returned by `decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:` is a result of failing `isKindOfClass:` checks, versus whether it was actually `nil` when during  `encodeWithCoder:`, could be to encode `[NSData data]` if it was indeed `nil` during encoding.

For example:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:_buffer ?: [NSMutableData data] forKey:@"buffer"];
}
```